# C++ write to front of file

Tags: c++, file, io

I need to open a file as ofstream and write to the front of the file, while preserving
the remaining contents of the file, which will be "moved".  Similar to "prepend"
a file.

Is this possible using the STL or boost ?

Answer (score 16):

No -- the language (or library) doesn't really make much difference here. Most file systems just don't allow it, full stop.

The usual way to get the same effect is to write your new data to a new file, then copy the data in the old file to the new file following the data you wrote.

Comment: How can you say it's impossible and then describe how to do it? Boost provides a portable filesystem library http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm with `boost::remove` which does in fact make a difference if you want to unlink the old file and make a new file — not that such is essential, or even a good way of implementing it. OP didn't ask for a one-liner, he asked for help.

Comment: He doesn’t describe how to do it; he describes the standard workaround for this problem.

Comment: Uh, being a workaround would imply accomplishing the task. More to the point, we use C++ because it's portable, and the language and library *do* make a difference because very specific features are used to solve the problem. See my answer.

Comment: there is a distinct but subtle difference here. jerry is not describing how to prepend to a file, he is creating a new file, then appending the old file. this accomplishes the same result, but is surely a lot more work for the operating system. (assuming the data to be prepended is small, and the file is large in comparison)

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't. And this has been asked here many times before. If you want to do this you have to create  new file, write the "prepend" data to it, then open the existing file and copy its contents to the new file.

Answer (score 1):

A new `iostream` class can wrap that functionality. This assumes your prepend data isn't too large to comfortably fit in memory. Use it like a regular `ofstream`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class prepend_ofstream
    : public std::ostringstream {
    std::filebuf file;
public:
    prepend_ofstream() {}
    prepend_ofstream( char const *name, openmode mode = out ) {
        open( name, mode );
    }
    ~prepend_ofstream() {
        if ( is_open() ) close();
    }
    void open( char const *name, openmode mode ) {
        if ( ! file.open( name, mode & binary | in | out ) ) {
            setstate( failbit );
        }
    }
    bool is_open() { return file.is_open(); }
    void close() {
        if ( ! is_open() ) {
            setstate( failbit );
            return;
        }
        char *strbuf = &str()[0];
        std::vector<char> buf( str().size() );
        int rdsz;
        do {
            rdsz = file.sgetn( &buf[0], buf.size() );
            file.pubseekoff( -rdsz, cur );
            file.sputn( strbuf, buf.size() );
            file.pubseekoff( 0, cur ); // "update the output sequence"
            std::copy( &buf[0], &buf[0]+rdsz, strbuf );
        } while ( rdsz == buf.size() );
        file.sputn( &buf[0], rdsz );
        if ( ! file.close() ) {
            setstate( failbit );
        }
    }
};
```

Typically features are added through new stream *buffer* classes, not actual streams, but in this case the new functionality is in `close`, which is unfortunately not virtual.