# Replace one specific line in a huge text file

Tags: c#

I want to replace one specific line in a text file. The simplest solution would be:

```
public void ModifyFile(string path, int line, string targetText) {
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    lines[line] = targetText;
    File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
}
```

The thing is, if the file is huge enough, I will get a `System.OutOfMemoryException` because [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tries to load the whole file in memory, instead of a line-by-line way.

I know there is another way to read a specific line with less memory cost:

```
var line = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(line-1).Take(1).ToString();
```

How can I replace over that line in the file?

I'm looking for something like [FileStream.Write Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var writer = File.OpenWrite(path);
writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(targetText), 
    offset, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(targetText));
```

But it's difficult to know `offset`.

Is there a better way to do that?

### **-- UPDATE --**

The temporary file solution suggested by answers works great.
At the same time, I am wondering, is there a **specific case solution** without creating a temporary file, if I know `line` is a small number (**line < 100** let's say)? There must be a better solution if I want to change the 10th line in a text file having 100m lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748282/quickly-replace-first-line-of-large-file?rq=1 for specific case solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just read the file a line at a time using streams, and copy the contents into a new file, or rename the old file with a backup name and then process with;

```
string line;
int couinter = 0;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(new_path);

while((text = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   // Check for your content and replace if required here  
   if ( counter == line ) 
      text = targetText;

   writer.writeline(text);
   counter++;
}

reader.Close();
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Is there a specific case solution if I know `line` is a small number (<100 let's say), while the file has many rows(> 100 million)?

Comment: This is the implementation of exact algorithm that I mentioned in my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is open the FileStrem with StreamReader (which provides ReadLine method). Now read line by line and write the output to a temporary file line by line. When you are on the desired line just change the line.